# Access Query - How do I create a field that counts all matching records of a column rather than the row?

Tags: ms-access, expression, formula

I'm not sure how to phrase this exactly, so hopefully what I'm trying to do will make sense.

I have a crosstab query in Access that I want a field to show the total number of matching values in the query results that match a value in the record. For example:

```
 [ID]       [Name]     [Unit]     [Unit_Total]
   1          A          M1           2
   2          B          M1           2
   3          B          M2           1
```

For [Unit_Total], I want to count the total number of times the value in [Unit] appears in the query results.

I feel like this should be fairly easy to do. I've tried building various expressions for quite a while, but haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.ID,
       t.Name,
       t.Unit,
       (select count(*) from [table] t1 where t1.Unit = t.Unit) as Unit_Total
from [table] t
```

That's the quick and readable way to do it. If performance is a concern, you can aggregate the table then join it back to itself, like:

```
select t.ID,
       t.Name,
       t.Unit,
       t2.Unit_Total
from [table] t
join (
    select t.Unit, count(*) as Unit_Total
    from [table] t1
    group by t.Unit
) t2
    on t2.Unit = t.Unit
```